# How to hide toolbar in a fragment and preserve statusbar color?

Tags: android, kotlin

How to hide toolbar in a fragment and preserve statusbar color?

I am trying to hide toolbar using this line in onCreateView:

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.hide()
```

And it works, however statusbar color goes gray.

Sorry if i am asking common question, but i couldn`t find an answer for it.

UPD

themes.xml

```
<style name="Theme.PP" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>

    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/teal_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/cyan_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/cyan_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="Theme.PP.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.PP.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="Theme.PP.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Toolbar declared within main_activity.xml

```
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.AppBarLayout.PrimarySurface"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        />
```

Comment: I just tried replicating the same. But it stays the same for me. So can you please share more code like what other changes are you making around that? are you changing theme or some other changes?

Comment: @MayurGajra well, I am using navigation drawer, so my toolbar is declared within main activity xml file. Maybe it has something to do with this? I made an upd in the post. I am totally new to programming, so i may not understand core idea behind this concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is with your `windowTranslucentStatus` in your theme.

If you read the documentation it says:

> Flag indicating whether this window requests a translucent status bar.

So it doesn't take the color your provide. You need to remove that to take `colorPrimaryDark`,  `colorPrimaryVariant` or other status bar color to take effect.